# Atom Beautify( JS Beautifier)

Tags: javascript, sass, atom

Не понимаю, как заставить Atom Beautify( JS Beautifier) работать. Для HTML/CSS всё работает. Но для SASS нет никаких действий. A .js форматирует как HTML. Есть какой-нибудь подробный гайд по настройке/использованию JS Beautifier???

Comment: С чего взял, что должен sass форматировать?